# Como baixar momentaneamente o sons das outras aplicações

Tags: android

Estou a utilizar a Classe MediaPlayer para tocar um som de alerta na minha app. O meu problema é que se o usuário estiver a ouvir musica através de uma outra aplicação, o som emitido pela minha Classe MediaPlayer pode não ser percebido. Existe a possibilidade de baixar momentaneamente o som das outra aplicações (igual ao que acontece com a Classe NotificationManager)?

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.alert_19);
            mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Acredito que tenha a ver com prioridade de som, veja [essa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26190070/5524514) no SOEn, e se alguma das repostas te atende.

Comment: @DiegoF, apliquei valores de 0 e 1 à prioridade, e testei o som em paralelo com a aplicação da Google "Play Musica" a tocar uma musica. O som da aplicação da Google não baixou momentaneamente o seu som quando eu executei a reprodução do som da minha aplicação! Que valores devo atribuir à prioridade,  para que a minha aplicação consiga baixar o som das outras aplicações?